# how to read Kudu by Impala in spark2

Tags: impala, apache-spark-2.0, apache-kudu

i want to read Kudu by Impala in spark2-shell, failed on many ways :(

enter spark2-shell:

```
spark2-shell --jars commons-codec-1.3.jar,hive_metastore.jar,httpclient-4.1.3.jar,ImpalaJDBC41.jar,libthrift-0.9.0.jar,ql.jar,slf4j-log4j12-1.5.11.jar,zookeeper-3.4.6.jar,commons-logging-1.1.1.jar,hive_service.jar,httpcore-4.1.3.jar,libfb303-0.9.0.jar,log4j-1.2.14.jar,slf4j-api-1.5.11.jar,TCLIServiceClient.jar
```

my code:

```
spark.read.format("jdbc") .option("driver","com.cloudera.impala.jdbc41.Driver")
.option("url","jdbc:impala:Domainname")
//.option("databaseName","default") also use impala::default
.option("dbtable", "impala::default.tablename")
.load()
```

By the way i got "impala::default.tablename" by `desc formatted tablename`.

outputs:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:72)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:113)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:45)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:330)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:125)
  ... 48 elided
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to connect to Kudu directly with Spark then connecting via Impala
for that documentation is here https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2017/02/up-and-running-with-apache-spark-on-apache-kudu/

Impala gives competitive performace to Spark SQL

Comment: This answer didn't sum up the contents of the link and now the link is broken